NextJS rewrite does not delete URL search param
I have an email auth and after user clicks the button to access my website I have to check whether they have tokens or not. When they are redirected to my page from Gmail they have verification_token=** searchParam and if they have already been authorized I have to delete it.
As NextJS docs say, I have to use NextResponse.rewrite function in middleware.ts with deleting that token but next just shows the page with the same search param. I use app router and Next 14
As I mentioned, I used rewrite function with deleting the searchParam with url.searchParams.delete('verification_token'); but it does not help. The param is still there.
I have tried multiple variants with nextResponse.redirect etc. but nothing helped.

The NextResponse.rewrite function proxies requests, so the url shouldn't change. Using NextResponse.redirect worked for me:
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export function middleware(req) {
  const nextUrl = req.nextUrl;

  if (nextUrl.searchParams.has("verification_token")) {
    nextUrl.searchParams.delete("verification_token");
    return NextResponse.redirect(nextUrl);
  } else {
    return NextResponse.next();
  }
}


Hello! This helped but I really don't understand why redirect hasn't worked when I used it exactly as you did but without if statement (searchParams.has).
I mean, every request which comes through the middleware has the verification token and function which deletes it still has to work as expected.
My question is - why should we check .has(token) here implicitly?

If you don't check whether the token is in the URL, you will be redirected infinitely and get an "x redirected you too many times" error. Even after the token is removed from the URL, you will still be "redirected" to the same page, causing a loop.
